# Python Beautifulsoup Как достать ссылку из тега <a>?

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup, link

Почему я не могу спарсить ссылку из тега ? Я делаю вроде всё правильно.
Этот вопрос связан с моим предыдущим вопросом.

Я хочу, чтобы выдавало ссылку, а выдаёт None.

Сам код:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('section', class_='proposition')

    cars = []
    for item in items:

        titles = None
        if titles_tag := item.find('div', class_='proposition_title'):
            if titles_1_tag := titles_tag.find('h3'):
                titles = titles_1_tag.get_text(strip=True)

        links = None
        if links_tag := item.find('section', class_='proposition'):
            if links_1_tag := links_tag.find('a'):
                links = links_1_tag.get('href')

        usd_prices = None
        if usd_prices_tag := item.find('div', class_='proposition_price'):
            if usd_prices_1_tag := usd_prices_tag.find('span'):
                usd_prices = usd_prices_1_tag.get_text(strip=True)

        cars.append(
            {
                'title': titles,
                'link': links,
                'usd_price': usd_prices,
            }
        )

        print(cars)
```

Проблема в:

```
links = None
        if links_tag := item.find('section', class_='proposition'):
            if links_1_tag := links_tag.find('a'):
                links = links_1_tag.get('href')
```

Если нужно, то скину сайт, на котором я парсю.

Comment: Ссылку на сайт в студию.

Comment: Вот: https://auto.ria.com/newauto/search/?page=1&modelId=0&generationId=0&baseId=0&equipId=0
Это сайт, который хочу парсить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот код:

```
links = None
   if links_tag := item.find('section', class_='proposition'):
       if links_1_tag := links_tag.find('a'):
           links = links_1_tag.get('href')
```

Замените на этот:

```
links = item.find('a', class_='proposition_link').get('href')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Snowman222 [Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/389694)