# Как получить содержание <a> python?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4, request

я сейчас изучаю парсин на python request, bs4 и столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне нужно из
`auf = [<h3><a href="https://b-reading.ru/page/korabl-prizrak-i-drugie-uzhasnye-istorii">КОРАБЛЬ-ПРИЗРАК И ДРУГИЕ УЖАСНЫЕ ИСТОРИИ</a></h3>]`
Получить ссылку и название.
Я пытался воспользоваться `auf.find_all('a'):` но выдалась ошибка:
`Traceback (most recent call last):`

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

url = 'https://b-reading.ru/search/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE'

headerss = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

req = requests.get(url, headers = headerss)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)

auf = soup.find('ul', 'mso-search-res').find_all('h3')

print (auf)
```

ссылка на сайт: https://b-reading.ru/search/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE

Comment: find_all вы ищите все "а", а вам надо заходить в класс, оттуда дергать href.
посмотри вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381184/python-beautifulsoup-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-a)

Comment: @gruvi не работает, выдает туже ошибку, можете написать вариант при котором как вы думаете будет всё работать.

Comment: Уважаемый пользователь! Для того, чтобы вам помогать точечно, необходим код программы (хотя бы минимально-работающая часть), ссылка на страницу (или код страницы).  В противном случае, задавая подобные вопросы, вы будете получать подобные ответы.
Без обид, просто нужно выкладывать вопрос в более развернутом виде.

Comment: @Gruvi Вся необходимая информация добавлена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с результатом find_all надо работать как со списком и обрабатывать каждый элемент отдельно:

```
auf = soup.find('ul', 'mso-search-res').find_all('h3')

for h3 in auf:
    a = h3.find('a')
    print(a['href'], a.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать метод find, т.к. у вас есть только одна ссылка, с которой вы работаете. Если вам нужен текст ссылки, то пишите find('a').text , если вам нужен какой -нибудь элемент ссылки, например домен, то пишите find('a').get('href')